# jstree rename all nodes from a class

Tags: jquery, jstree

Good morning,

I'm using a jstree that looks like this

```
<div id="jstree">
  <ul id="root">
    <li>2013
      <ul>
        <li class="jan">Jan</li>
        <li class="feb">Feb</li>
        <li class="mar">Mar</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>2014
      <ul>
        <li class="jan">Jan</li>
        <li class="feb">Feb</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I want to do is rename all Nodes from class "feb" for example, but my attempts with rename_node or set_text doesn't work. Can someone please tell me how I can do this?

EDIT : By rename, I mean change the html text inside the node. So for example, if I want to change all Node of class feb and name them "February", the Output for all node of class feb will be

```
<div id="jstree">
  <ul id="root">
    <li>2013
      <ul>
        <li class="jan">Jan</li>
        <li class="feb">February</li>
        <li class="mar">Mar</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>2014
      <ul>
        <li class="jan">Jan</li>
        <li class="feb">February</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

EDIT 2 : I made a simplified code so you can understand where my problem is. Here is my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/themes/default/style.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="menu" class="ui-widget-content">
      <div id="jstree">
        <ul id="root">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/functions.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And Here is my javascript file (saved in jquery/functions.js):

```
$(function() {
  var actDate = new Date("2014-10-17");
  var frstDate = new Date("2013-05-10");
  var aD = new Date(frstDate);

  // The following double loop create the tree nodes
  for(var i = frstDate.getFullYear(); i <= actDate.getFullYear(); i++){
    aD.setFullYear(i);

    var yearNode = $('<li>', {
      class: i.toString()
    }).text(i.toString());

    var year = $('<ul>');
    year.appendTo(yearNode);

    for(var j = 0; j <= 11; j++){ // jan = 0, feb = 1 etc.
      aD.setMonth(j);
      if(aD > frstDate && aD < actDate){
      // Add for loop for Days here
      if(j==0){$('<li>', {class: 'jan'}).text("jan").appendTo(year);}
      else if(j==1){$('<li>', {class: 'feb'}).text("feb").appendTo(year);}
      else if(j==2){$('<li>', {class: 'mar'}).text("mar").appendTo(year);}
      else if(j==3){$('<li>', {class: 'apr'}).text("apr").appendTo(year);}
      else if(j==4){$('<li>', {class: 'may'}).text("may").appendTo(year);}
      else if(j==5){$('<li>', {class: 'jun'}).text("jun").appendTo(year);}
      else if(j==6){$('<li>', {class: 'jul'}).text("jul").appendTo(year);}
      else if(j==7){$('<li>', {class: 'aug'}).text("aug").appendTo(year);}
      else if(j==8){$('<li>', {class: 'sep'}).text("sep").appendTo(year);}
      else if(j==9){$('<li>', {class: 'oct'}).text("oct").appendTo(year);}
      else if(j==10){$('<li>', {class: 'nov'}).text("nov").appendTo(year);}
      else if(j==11){$('<li>', {class: 'dec'}).text("dec").appendTo(year);}
      }
    }
    yearNode.appendTo($('#root'));
  }

  $('#jstree').jstree(); // creation of the tree : tree is normally displayed

  // The following prints "not done"
  if($('#jstree').jstree().rename_node(
    $('#jstree').jstree().get_node(".feb"),
    "February"))
  {
    alert("done");
  }
  else{
    alert("not done"); 
  }
  $('#jstree').jstree('rename_node', [$('#j1_10'), "February"]); // same, does not work
  $('li ul li.feb').text('February'); // does not work neither.

  // I tried other things (like set_text) but none of them worked.
});
```

I enter a first date and the actual Date and a Tree of month and year is shown in a jstree. The tree is displayed correctly, but all of my tries didn't work and I don't understand where i'm doing it wrong.

Comment: What do you mean be rename?

Comment: I mean change the html inside the <li>. For example wenn i rename node of class feb, the outpout is <li class="feb">February</li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

first, we have to set check_callback to true when we create the tree:

```
  $('#jstree').jstree({
    "core" : {
      // so that create works
      "check_callback" : true
    }
  });
```

Then, use the function

```
$('#jstree').jstree().rename_node({"id":"j1_10"}, 'February');
```

for example, and that works :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's jQuery try:

```
$("li.feb").text("February");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, but this code does not work in my tree. Do you know if i have to add some options in the tree to make this command work? I simply initialized my tree $('#jstree').jstree();

Answer (score 1):

Just use jquery like:

```js
$("#jstree ul li.feb").text("February");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jstree">
  <ul id="root">
    <li>2013
      <ul>
        <li class="jan">Jan</li>
        <li class="feb">Feb</li>
        <li class="mar">Mar</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>2014
      <ul>
        <li class="jan">Jan</li>
        <li class="feb">Feb</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this jquery command does not work in my tree, even if I make a refresh after. I think the Problem comes from the jstree object (when I create it simply with $('#jstree').jstree();). Maybe I must set some options to make it work? Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could keep your full month names in a JavaScript object:

```
var monthNames = {
    jan: "January",
    feb: "February",
    mar: "March",
    apr: "April",
    may: "May",
    jun: "June",
    jul: "July",
    aug: "August",
    sep: "September",
    oct: "October",
    nov: "November",
    dec: "December"
}
```

And then loop through your months, finding the appropriate elements and setting the text within:

```
$jstree = $('#jstree');
$.each(monthNames, function(i,v){
    $jstree.find('li.'+i).text(v);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Leq0ggnt/)

Comment: thanks for your help. :) I was planing on doing it like this, but it seems that the function .text(text); does not work in my tree. The tree is initialized simply with $('#jstree').jstree(); and there is no problems by the creation and the display of the tree. I'm wondering where the Problem could come from :/ Maybe I need to add some options in the creation of the tree.

Comment: Are you placing this code snippet after you call the plugin? I'm afraid I have no experience using JSTree so I can't advise as far as the plugin options are concerned. Maybe it might be easier if you were to reproduce your issue in an [online demo](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I placed the code in function.js, so after the plugin is called in the html file. I made an edit 2. It's a simplified version of my code that reproduce the problem that I have.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the code where you're initialising the jstree? At what point are you calling this code? The code below should work:

```js
$('li ul li.feb').text('February');
// Optionally update other months also
$('li ul li.mar').text('March');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jstree">
  <ul id="root">
    <li>2013
      <ul>
        <li class="jan">Jan</li>
        <li class="feb">Feb</li>
        <li class="mar">Mar</li>
      <ul>
    </li>
    <li>2014
      <ul>
        <li class="jan">Jan</li>
        <li class="feb">Feb</li>
      <ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply :). Your code does not work by me. I made an EDIT 2 that shows a simplified Version of my code (and that reproduce the problem that I have).